# Дух удаляет бесхозные вопросы независимо от ответов?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, предложение

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/523805/revisions

> за Сообщение удалено проголосовали Дух сообщества ♦

Насколько я понимаю, это удаление вызвано удалением пользователя, задавшего вопрос.

Но ведь у вопроса было 4 ответа с положительным рейтингом, топовый с +6. Неужели для Духа это ничего не значит? Такая обработка кажется нелогичной.

Comment: кодгольф под угрозой?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Это действительно нелогично, но именно так действует алгоритм удаления: если пользователь удалён, вопросы с отрицательным рейтингом удаляются, даже если у них были ответы с положительным рейтингом.

С 2013 года стоит предложение сохранять такие вопросы: [A question should not be deleted by the user deletion algorithm if it has upvoted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199860). Оно не отклонено, так что есть надежда... на данный момент всё, что мы можем сделать, это  проголосовать за: чем больше голосов, тем более оно заметно, тем выше шансы на претворение в действие.